# Can't import Firebase library to AndroidStudio

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I can't import the "import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;" for my Android Studio.

I checked everything already. All build gradle are setted with the latest Firebase version.

The only import that allows me to do is "FirebaseAuthException" and "FirebaseUser"

Someone help me. thank you.

Project Build.Gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Build.gradle(Module:app)

```
    repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.rick.teddyfy"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Design layout
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.3'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    //firebase authentication
    'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: you can see better here: 
http://prntscr.com/gvqmjt
http://prntscr.com/gvqmr8

Comment: Post the entire file as an edit, not as a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency has **syntax** errors, it should be like this:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.6'
```

Comment: Solve the problem.Thank you.